# How do I use my own version of a typings file to resolve typescript compile errors?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The library we're using has some code that causes problems with ES6. But the library and the typings file aren't being updated. We'd like to have a clean lint/compile and know the line to remove from the .d.ts file to make it work. How can we make use of this file?

Answer (score 0):

Given an example library called fred, I ended up creating a local file in a location like this:

```
typings-ours/fred/fred.d.ts
```

and then ran

```
typings install "file:typings-ours/fred/fred.d.ts" --save --global
```

This resulted in the change to typings.json below:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "registry:dt/body-parser#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "fred": "file:typings-ours/fred/fred.d.ts",
    "cookie-parser": "registry:dt/cookie-parser#1.3.4+20160316155526",
    etc...
  }
}
```